# D Language fails to display german Umlaute on Windows?

Tags: string, encoding, character-encoding, cross-platform, d

[image]

As you can see, D fails to output german Umlaute. At least on Windows. On Linux or BSD the same program outputs the string as I've saved it.

I already tried wstring or dstring, but the output is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D will output UTF-8 regardless of the operating system. How the output will be interpreted depends on how it is displayed. In this particular case, it looks like your IDE is interpreting the output as if it was encoded in the Windows-1252 encoding.

For the standard Windows console, you could change the output encoding by calling `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)`, but note that this may have some undesired side effects (you should restore the codepage before your progam exits, and batch files may not run while the console output codepage is set to 65001).

Comment: I feel uncomfortable changing global settings of my console. Isn't there a cleaner solution? Why is C++- or Java-Ouput not affected by this problem?

Comment: `SetConsoleOutputCP` is not a global setting, it changes the setting for the current window.

Comment: C++ and Java probably do not output UTF-8.

Comment: Java's runtime most likely does check what is the underlying operating system and adjusts the output encoding... Perhaps Phobos should do the same.

Answer (score 4):

CyberShadows post guided me to an acceptable answer. :-)

In Eclipse it is possible to change the output-encoding without changing global settings of the OS.
Go to Run --> Run-Configurations...
[image]

There select the Common-Tab and change the encoding to UTF-8. Now german Umlaute are displayed correctly. At least in Eclipse. :-)

Another possibility is to use https://babun.github.io/ . It is a Cygwin-based Shell that ouputs UTF-8:
[image]